# Firebase read calculations for document queries?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Quick question about how firestore reads are calculated. Say I have a collection with 100 items in it, and I do

`citiesRef.order(by: "name").limit(to: 3)`

This would technically have to look at all 100 items, order them by name, and then return 3. Would this count for 3 reads or would it count for 100 reads, since we're looking at 100 items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the above query returns 3 documents then it would count as 3 reads.

> You are charged for each document read, write, and delete that you perform with Cloud Firestore.

> Charges for writes and deletes are straightforward. For writes, each set or update operation counts a single write.

> Charges for reads have some nuances that you should keep in mind. The following sections explain these nuances in detail

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations

Comment: Peter you may add the link to the sections!